# Using JavaScript to center multiple divs in a fluid layout

Tags: javascript, css, padding, html

I'm trying to align multiple divs in the center of a container div. I am using the modulus function to work out the padding needed from the left hand side of the page. Here is the JavaScript I am using:

**JavaScript**

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", winResize, false);
var width, leftPad, space, boxWidth;

winResize();

function winResize() {
    width = document.getElementById('body').offsetWidth;
    boxWidth = 350 + 10 + 10;
    space = width % boxWidth;
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = width + '....' + space;
    leftPad = space / 2;
    document.getElementById('container').style.paddingLeft = leftPad + 'px';
    document.getElementById('container').style.width -= leftPad;

};
```

The **HTML** is as follows:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

And the **CSS**:

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#container .block {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: 4e4e4e;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

My problem is with this code, the padding on the left pushes the container div to the right, which makes the page wider than the window. I have tried removing the padding from the width of the container (in the bottom line of the winResize function) but this doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a way I can remove this "excess div" with CSS padding/margins?

Answer (score 1):

What I can perceive is that you are trying to make container look in the center of your page, js is not required to do it and prefer not use js to position static elements in your page ever.

Here is the css you should use to make it come in center and fluidic

```
 #container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
 }

 #container .block {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;    
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
 }
```

Also you can see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ghFRv/

Comment: Wow I really put too much thought into it! Thanks.

Comment: Didn't understand!! 'doesn't seem to like putting content in the div', adding content has to be done via javascript but making it come in center should not involve js

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if there is any reason why you want to CENTER an html element?

This is a CSS job and CSS does a very good job at it.

If you want to center your DIVS you could use `margin: 0 auto;` on the .block.
This would center your layout and keep the elements block level as well.

Your css would look like this:

```
#container {
    width: 100%; /*Remove the float, it's not needed. Elements align top-left standard.*/
}

#container div.block {
    width: 350px; /*Makes it possible for margin to center the box*/
    height: 350px; 
    background: #4e4e4e; /*background is the shorthand version*/
    margin: 10px auto; /*10px to keep your margin, auto to center it.*/
}
```

This should get rid of your problem, and makes your page load faster since theres no JS plus, the layout can never be "disabled" due to JS being disabled.

Hope this helped, if it did don't forget to upvote / accept answer

‐ Sid

Comment: I would upvote if I had the rep on this account, and if it didn't screw up when you put content in the divs

Comment: Screw up the content in the div's? Whats happening there, quite curious.